# Negative/inverted screen when I hit a dialog / "interrupt"

Tags: windows-10

My screen sometimes turns negative/inverted in colors when I hit a dialog / end-of-actions. The most obvious one is when I have no more steps to undo in PowerPoint of Excel and press CTRL+Z again my screen shows inverted / negative momentarily, ca. 1 second. See below.

Any idea if that is an error or setting? I would like to get rid of it.

Windows 10.0.19044

So picture 1 is normal, picture 2 is inverted.

[image: Normal]

[image: Inverted screen]

Comment: I've not seen it on Windows, but I'd guess that's the 'error beep' equivalent for hearing-impaired, in Accessibility mode. The Mac can do a similar thing. Check your Accessibility settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment given by Tetsujin gave me the right terms to Google on. Found a [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/inverted-colours-when-a-system-sound-is-played/d21812ed-b502-4f95-977d-45d6c2956228) that explained:

Go to Control Panel > Easy of Access > Replace sounds with visual cues

There you can configure / disable it.